# How to make discord.py tempmute

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I already have a tempmute command, but I don't know how to change the time from seconds to minute

I want my tempmute command so I can write "tempmute <@user> 30m (reason), how do I do it so that s=seconds, m=minutes, h=hour, and d=day. The default right now are seconds

This is my code right now:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=0, reason=None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = "no reason provided"
    
    if member.id == ctx.author.id:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you can't mute yourself")

    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    guild = ctx.guild

    if not role:
        role = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(role, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="tempmuted", description=f"{member.mention} was tempmuted ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    embed.add_field(name="reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="time left for the mute:", value=f"{time}", inline=False)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could always do:

```py
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, s=0, m=0, h=0, d=0, reason=None):
    time = s + 60*m + 60*60*h + 60*60*24*d
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with discord's Python library but assuming that when you write `50m` your `time` argument is the string `"50m"`:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=0, reason=None):
  mults = {"m": 60, "h": 60 * 60, "d": 60 * 60 * 24}
  try:
    seconds = int(time)
  except ValueError:
    seconds = int(time[:-1]) * mults.get(time[-1], 1)
  # ...
```

It will check if it can just parse `time` into a number and treat it as seconds, otherwise it will assume the number + multiplier format and look up the last character of `time` in the multiplier dictionary.

There are some edge cases with invalid values that you might have to catch.